# Creating a picture of a map with a recurssive function

Tags: haskell, gloss

i'm using haskell gloss for the first time and I'm having some trouble, in this code:

```
-- the initial c and l will be imagine for dimension 9: (-160) 160 
-- (so the square ends in the center of the window

--         column;  line;   dimension   
drawmap :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Picture
drawmap c l d = (drawline x c l d) : (drawmap xs c (l+40) d)

drawline :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Picture
drawline c l d = if (d>0) then (Translate c l $ Color red (circle 20)) : (drawline (c+40) l (d-1))
                          else (Translate c l $ Color red (circle 20))
```

The only question I have right now is with the type, because I need it to be the type Picture, and not [Picture], any help?

And also, how do i make this stop point:

```
drawline _ _ 0 = Nothing or []
```

I know this is not acceptable, but how do I tell it when to stop doing circles?

This is not pratical at all, is just an example very simple, if someone helps me understand this I can after apply what I really need to do.

Comment: 1. you can use `pictures` function for [Picture] -> Picture.

Comment: 2. Just use helping function for `drawline` and make `drawline` using that helping function and `pictures`

Comment: P.S. use different type for Column, Line, Dimension, not just use comment.

Comment: I only used the comments to explain it here.

Comment: I have Column,Line and Dimension set as INT and I can't use int here xD

Comment: Then use other name, but a type, not a comment.

Comment: One more thing, what shoud i use in the place of:

     drawline _ _ 0 = Nothing or []

Comment: It's my second point. Use helping function that generate [Picture] and return `[]`

Comment: Yes, I already solved, now i just need to place my functions to put what i want insteed of a bunch of circles in the screen. Thank you